# Backup tool for windows 10

Tags: windows, backup

For years I was using Symantec system recovery 2011 to backup up to 5 PCs with Windows 7 on a small network. Now I need to migrate all PCs to Windows 10 and SSR 2011 is no longer supported (new version is called Veritas System Recovery).

So I am looking for the alternative. My main requirements are:

- Full/incremental/diff backups
- Drive backup, folder backup, individual files backup
- Scheduler
- Multiple backup jobs
- Backup in the background with minimal performance impact
- Backup location: HDD, network shared folder, FTP
- To be able to browse recovery points and restore multiple historical versions of the files
- Backup destination management
- Space - what to do when there is no space for new backup
- Retention policy

Answer (score 1):

[Syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm) might be something to look at. I've only tested it at my house, trying to see if it would benefit my work place, but it seems to cover many of the things you're looking for.

There is a free version, where you can create 1 user account, on the server, and then install the client software on as many PCs as you want. The user account is where you define the location of the repository, among other settings, such as bandwidth throttling, disk quota, and much more. So, you sign into the client with the user account created on the server, and then specify what you want to backup on that specific client.

So, I have a user named "backup" that has is repository pointed to a second hdd on my server at "F:\backup." On the client software, I have signed in using the credentials for the backup user, which then lets my client know where the repository is, among other settings mentioned earlier. On the client, I can create multiple profiles, such as "test" and "home", which allow me to change settings unique to each profile, that will then save its files on the server as "F:\backup\test" and "F:\backup\home" respectively.

I don't know if this software covers all your requirements, as I've only tested this at my house, but it might be worth a look.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Acronis True Image 2017 New Generation has all capabilities I need.